# NSLocalizedString using external sources in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, localization, localizable.strings

Is there a way to make the localization or Localizable.strings read from directories outside NSBundle?

I am trying to make my app read localizations from a file that is downloaded via a server, is there a way good way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to write your own MyLocalizedString function which reads the file manually. A .strings file is actually an old type of property list, so it can be read using the `NSPropertyListSerialization` class like this:

```
id plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization
               propertyListWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:stringsFilePath]
                            options:0
                             format:NULL
                              error:&error];
```

`plist` is just an NSDictionary, so you can read a string value from the result like this:

```
[plist objectForKey:@"my_string"];
```

You should probably implement some sort of cache so that you aren't parsing the whole file for each string lookup.

Note that if you are using `genstrings` and the other related command line tools, you can use the following option to specify the name of your custom lookup function:

```
Usage: genstrings [OPTION] file1.[mc] ... filen.[mc]

...[snip]...

-s substring             substitute 'substring' for NSLocalizedString.
```

If these strings files are being uploaded to a server, you can improve performance in the app a bit by first converting them to the binary plist format (this is what Xcode would normally do during a build):

```
plutil -convert binary1 myStrings.strings
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put together the pieces yourself. There isn't any built-in facility to do that. Your localizations can just be serialized dictionaries with the development language string as the key and the localized string as the value. You can serialize as a plist, which may be most convenient to edit, or using a keyed archive, which may be more compact.